# Idiom the last monkey

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

We have an idiom in Spain: **ser el último mono** (to be [someone] the last monkey)

Let me quote the DRAE (Diccionario de la Real Academia Española de la Lengua)

**[ser alguien el último mono](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PeswonB%7CPevMcDo)**

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser insignificante

Translated: to be a [nobody](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nobody)

A more elaborated explanation [from [here]](https://palabraspormadrid.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/el-ultimo-mono.html)

> **Ser el último mono** dentro de un grupo: la última persona a la que le cuentan algo, la última persona
>   que recibe una propuesta, el último al que avisan para alguna
>   actividad, la persona a la que nadie pide su opinión

Translated

> **Being the last monkey** in a group: the last one to be told something,
>   the last one to receive a proposal, the last one to be invited to an
>   event, the person never asked about his opinion

Used in a workplace environment, it may mean that there are a lot of bosses and few real workers. Being the **last** means that you can not delegate, that you have to do the job.

Is there any equivalent idiom in English?

Let me illustrate the term with a pair of images from the great Argentinian artist known as **Quino** showing how you can be the last monkey working for a Big Company.

[image: Illustration of one person rowing a boat filled with people]

[CAPTION:

What? You don't want to keep rowing?? I'm puzzled, Fernández!!!

Are we or are we not in the same boat?]

[image: Illustration showing a crew team with one rower and four coxswains]

EDITED: Thanks to @FumbleFingers' comment, I've searched the Spanish idiom's origin.

According to [Instituto Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58700&Lng=0), it comes from the proverb

> El último mono es el que se ahoga / The last monkey is the one who drowns at the end

The Instituto marks this English proverb as equivalent

> The devil take the hindmost

But it may have some kind of relation with

> as long as they [Gibraltar's monkeys] remain, so will the British

Who knows? No proof has been found to back up or deny this point.

Comment: This puts me in mind of the saying about [Gibraltar’s Barbary macaques](https://www.newstatesman.com/gibraltar/newstatesman-gibraltar/2015/03/gibraltar-s-barbary-macaques-long-they-remain-so-will) - *as long as they remain, so will the British*. I can't help thinking the Spanish idiom being discussed here is in some way *connected* - the question is: *Which came first, and did it actually **lead to** the other?*

Comment: Note that in In BrE at least, it's quite normal to refer to someone as [*the lowest of the low*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+lowest+of+the+low%22) to mean they're "at the bottom of the social heap".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't get if you are joking or not. According to Instituto Cervantes, both are not connected. https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58700&Lng=0 This Spanish idiom's origin is a proverb: El último mono es el que se ahoga. (The last monkey is the one who drowns at the end) Whose equivalent in English is: The devil take the hindmost

Comment: I don't read Spanish, but even after shoving your link through Google Translate, I don't see anything there specifically denying what looks like a distinct possibility of a connection to me. Come to that, it gives no indication of whether the Spanish "saying" actually predates the "British" one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So you are not joking. I added the source for completion but the relevant parts are in the comment. Translated.

Comment: [This Spanish guy](http://roboticslab.uc3m.es/roboticslab/user/82) says *we have an idiomatic expression to describe my position here and can be translated as the following: I'm the last monkey here. If this does not make any sense to you, better for both, you and me ;p* So I suppose I should be "glad" I don't know either the exact meaning or the etymology. It could be a more recent derivation through the Spanish equivalent of *grease-monkeys = engineering minions*, for all I know.

Comment: Well, I *still* don't know exactly what the Spanish saying means! I very much doubt it corresponds to *Devil take the hindmost!* though, since that's closer in meaning to *Every man for himself!* - both of those effectively mean *You must look out for yourself, because no-one else will.* Your text seems to say the Spanish version of *I'm the last monkey* means *I'm so unimportant no-one bothers to tell me what's going on*, but I don't really see how that could apply to the guy in my link above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, I thought that you were joking again with the Spanish guy. I'll try to explain myself. Forget about the saying. Let's center in this idiom: being the last monkey. The guy you linked is working in an academic environment, in a department of an university, maybe he got an internship. (see next comment)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know exactly how university works in UK but here in Spain, if that guy writes a paper all by himself, a lot of people probably will figure as coauthors: his tutor, the head of department, the dean ... Maybe "The Spanish Guy"'s name not even appears. A lot of people take the credit about the investigation but "the Spanish Guy" is the only one that has really worked there. Get the work done, little recognition, all the pressure to finish the paper before the due date that everybody forgot to mention until the last minute ... The last monkey.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe he didn't mean ALL those things and just wanted to say that he is the lastest and less relevant member of the department.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ey, I have just found this! https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=code%20monkey 100% (American) English :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me answer my own question because I've just found the word that I was looking for.

But first let compile all the suggestions made in comments.

**[whipping boy](http://someone%20or%20something%20that%20is%20blamed%20or%20punished%20for%20problems%20that%20are%20caused%20by%20someone%20or%20something%20else)** (suggested by @ColleenV)

> someone or something that is blamed or punished for problems that are caused by someone or something else

**always the last to know** (suggested by @stangdon)

> idem

**[low man on the totem pole](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/low-man-on-the-totem-pole)** (suggested by @JeffZeitlin) Good one, Jeff. :-)

> someone who has the least important position in an organization

[**grease monkey** == engineering minions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grease-monkey) (suggested by @FumbleFingers) ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grease_monkey))

> someone whose job is repairing car or aircraft engines

And last but not least, I've just read this one in a profile from another Stack Exchange site

**[code monkey](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=code%20monkey)**

> A programmer who isn't actually involved in any aspect of conceptual
>   or design work, but simply writes code to specifications given

Being an IT professional myself this ones fits perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have an animal metaphor as well.

> He's the lowest down (or last) in the pecking order.

Another possibility:

> He's just an errand boy.

Figuratively that means he's on the lowest rung of the organizational ladder.

Comment: Good one! Down the pecking order makes me think in something like this https://lensoils.com/2017/01/20/the-real-pyramid-scheme-2/

Comment: Also ***low man on the totem pole***.